# "Method call expected" error in length method of int array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio raised this error in the length() method of a int array to get its length.
How to resolve?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try without `()` like so:

```
arrayTrofei.length;
```